# Print the sum of a list of integers without using sum()

Tags: python, list

I have a function defined below that prints each integer in the list, and it works perfectly. What I would like to do is create a second function that would call on or reutilize the `int_list()` function to display a sum of the list that's been generated.

I am not sure if that has been inherently performed by the code itself - I am rather new to the Python syntax.

```
integer_list = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]

def int_list(self):
    for n in integer_list
        index = 0
        index += n
        print index
```

Comment: I'm confused. `int_list` takes `self` as an argument, and does nothing with it, but iterates over something called `grades` that is never mentioned. It also adds each element of `grades` to *zero*, which is the same as just setting `index` to `n` at each iteration. So I'm lost. I get the sense the `int_list` function is a red herring to your real question.

Comment: Here is a simple example how to do that http://www.evaluzio.net/doc/d6475eaf58664b3f9342

Answer (score 7):

In your code, you're setting `index=0` in every loop, so it should be initialized before the `for`  loop:

```
def int_list(grades):   #list is passed to the function
    summ = 0 
    for n in grades:
        summ += n
        print summ
```

**output:**

```
int_list([5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45])
5
15
30
50
75
105
140
180
225
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the sum of a list of integers you have a few choices. Obviously the easiest way is `sum`, but I guess you want to learn how to do it yourself. Another way is to store the sum as you add it up:

```
def sumlist(alist):
    """Get the sum of a list of numbers."""
    total = 0         # start with zero
    for val in alist: # iterate over each value in the list
                      # (ignore the indices – you don't need 'em)
        total += val  # add val to the running total
    return total      # when you've exhausted the list, return the grand total
```

A third option is [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), which is a function that itself takes a function and applies it to the running total and each consecutive argument.

```
def add(x,y):
    """Return the sum of x and y. (Actually this does the same thing as int.__add__)"""
    print '--> %d + %d =>' % (x,y) # Illustrate what reduce is actually doing.
    return x + y

total = reduce(add, [0,2,4,6,8,10,12])
--> 0 + 2 =>
--> 2 + 4 =>
--> 6 + 6 =>
--> 12 + 8 =>
--> 20 + 10 =>
--> 30 + 12 =>

print total
42
```

Comment: Couldn't this also be accomplished with a lambda statement? This seams like the perfect situation for it.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Sure, there are all kinds of better ways to do it. I would write it `reduce(int.__add__, alist)` if `sum` didn't exist. It's academic, though, since `sum` is really the right way to do it and we've been asked not to use it. For this answer, though, I'm trying to illustrate what's happening, so I thought writing out the function would be clearer.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee Why sure! But as my Grandpa always said, *why import it when you can get what you need right here?*

Answer (score 0):

```
integer_list = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45] #this is your list
x=0  #in python count start with 0
for y in integer_list: #use for loop to get count
    x+=y #start to count 5 to 45
print (x) #sum of the list
print ((x)/(len(integer_list))) #average
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]

#counter 
count = 0
total = 0

for number in list:
    count += 1
    total += number
#don'n need indent
print(total)
print(count)
# average 
average = total / count
print(average)
```

Comment: If you wonder why your answer is not upvoted - add some explanation about how your code works.

Answer (score 0):

You can used reduce function from functools module

```
from functools import module

s=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, integer_list)
```

output

```
225
```