# "SUM" a list without using "sum" in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sum

im trying to have the "sum" of a list only using those fonction
len(liste), sorted(liste), int(nombre), float(nombre), math.sqrt(nombre) abs(nombre)

pop = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

I try to do

```
for valeur in pop:
    tot = valeur + valeur
    print tot
```

but it return me the list
2
4
6
8
....

Comment: Did you mean, `tot = tot + valeur` ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555263/print-the-sum-of-a-list-of-integers-without-using-sum

Answer (score 3):

```
reduce(operator.add,my_list)
```

does not use `sum`

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
pop = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
sum = 0
for element in pop:
    sum += element
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

The intendation is wrong on the last line, so that gets called in the for loop.

This is the correct code:

```
pop = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
for valeur in pop:
    tot = valeur + valeur
print(tot)
```

https://repl.it/BzBG/0

Comment: This does not sum the list.