# How to add the values of a nested list without using sum built in function and using a nested loop

Tags: python

I have the following line of code

```
grades=[[54,67,18,19],[89,98,99,98],[26,16,13]]
```

How can I add the values of each nested list without using the sum built in method and using a nested for loop?

Comment: can you use nested for loop or not ? it is not clear..

Comment: @balderman yes I can, I just can’t use the sum built in function

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555263/print-the-sum-of-a-list-of-integers-without-using-sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add the values of each nested list

see below (assuming you want to sum each nested list)

```
totals = []
avg = []
grades=[[54,67,18,19],[89,98,99,98],[26,16,13]]
for g in grades:
  totals.append(0)
  for x in g:
    totals[-1] += x
  avg.append(totals[-1]/len(g))
print(totals)
```

output

```
[158, 384, 55]
```

Comment: Unrelated question, but to get the average how can I do that. Sparked my curiosity

Comment: @young.coder131 see the code. make sure you understand it.

Comment: I have a couple of questions. Did you append 0 at the beginning of the loop to have something in the list to later replace on?

Comment: One more is why are you going through the -1 index when adding what the value of x is?

Comment: - one is the index of the last element in a list

Answer (score 1):

```py
grades=[[54,67,18,19],[89,98,99,98],[26,16,13]]

sum = 0 # Acumulator
for l in grades: # For each list in grades
    for g in l:  # For each grade in current list
        sum += g # Sum current grade into the acumulator
print(sum) # Return 597
```

Comment: "values of each nested list" Sorry I got it wrong. I think @balderman is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of reduce to find the sum of elements in the list as below:

```
import functools 

grades=[[54,67,18,19],[89,98,99,98],[26,16,13]]

total = 0
res = []

for grade in grades:    
   res.append(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, grade))
print(res) #[158, 384, 55]
```